# Text align vertical within li

Tags: html, css

```
<ul id = "Software">
   <li id = "pdf1"> <img src="/Content/img/pdf.png">Catalogue</li>
   <li id = "pdf2"> <img src="/Content/img/pdf.png">Manual Data</li>
   <li id = "pdf3"> <img src="/Content/img/pdf.png">Technical Data</li>
   <li id = "software1">Software</li>
</ul>
```

The text in the list elements is appearing at the bottom. How to center it alongside the image?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
li img { vertical-align: middle; }
```

Answer (score 3):

[Demo jsBin](http://jsbin.com/atuvir/2/edit)

```
  ul li{
    list-style:none;
    display:inline-block;
    height:40px;
    line-height:40px;
  }
  li img{
    float:left;
    margin:5px;
  }
```

You need to set a `height` and same `line-height` for your `li` element;
for the containing images - set `float : left`

Answer (score 2):

Set the same `height` and `line-height`. This will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

To align text and image, you can use `margin-bottom:-5px` on image element, the number depends on the size of your image.