# aligning image and text inline

Tags: html, css

html code:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href=#>Upload</a></li>
    <li><a href=#>christin Bayes</a></li>
    <li><img src="image/john.jpg" height="30" width="30"></li>  
    <li><a href=#>SignOut</a></li>
</ul>
```

css:

```
ul li
{
    margin-left: 15px;
    display: inline;
    list-style: none;
}
```

i want the list items(upload,name,signout) aligning middle exactly like in facebook. plz suggest me

Comment: possible duplicate of [Text align vertical within li](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8416628/text-align-vertical-within-li)

Answer (score 1):

try this: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/JellyBelly/BkZHA/1/)

**HMTL**:

```
<ul class="MenuBar">
    <li><a href=#>Upload</a></li>
    <li><a href=#>christin Bayes</a></li>
    <li><img src="image/john.jpg" height="30" width="30" /></li>   
    <li><a href=#>SignOut</a></li>
</ul>​
```

**CSS**:

```
.MenuBar
{
    padding: 0px;
    border: 1px solid #036;
    font-size: 8pt;
    height: 30px;
}

.MenuBar li
{
    display: inline;
    padding-left: 15px;
    list-style:none;
    height: 30px;
}

.MenuBar li img 
{
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

​
Obviously you can choose to remove the border is only for testing.

Answer (score 0):

```
img {
    vertical-align:middle;
}
​
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. May be it helps you:

```
ul{   
    background: red;
    height: 30px;
}
ul li{
    margin-left:15px;
    display: table-cell;
    list-style: none;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 90px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JCWSU/)

Comment: Please do not simply post a fiddle as an answer. Answers should **always** include relevant code